# Converting visual studio to gradle

Tags: visual-studio, gradle

I am working with Visual Studio projects and a custom made make build system to build c/c++ projects for windows, linux, android etc. This is hard to maintain.

My question is: Is there any way to create a gradle project from visual studio project? Maybe not directly, like do a conversion via eg. cmake or something else?